# getting ValueError: Outputs of true_fn and false_fn must have the same type: int32, float32 while using tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, stat

Hope someone can help me with this or point me some hint/ideas I can fix this error.

I am trying to create a custom layer in SeqtoSeq model.I need to call the histogram in part of my code. however, when it touches this line of the code it raises an error:

```
ValueError: Outputs of true_fn and false_fn must have the same type: int32, float32
```

this is my code for the layer:

```
class entropy_measure(Layer):

    def __init__(self, beta,batch, **kwargs):
        self.beta = beta
        self.batch = batch
        self.uses_learning_phase = True
        self.supports_masking = True
        super(entropy_measure, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, x):
        return K.in_train_phase(self.rev_entropy(x, self.beta,self.batch), x)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {'beta': self.beta}
        base_config = super(entropy_measure, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

    def rev_entropy(self, x, beta,batch):

        value_ranges = [0.0, 10.0]
        nbins = 5   
        converted_x = tf.cast(x,tf.float32)
        new_f_w_t = tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins(converted_x, value_ranges, nbins)

        return new_f_w_t
```

I call this layer using:

```
encoded = entropy_measure(beta=0.08,batch=BATCH_SIZE)(encoded)
```

This code written with keras tensorflow backend.

Any idea what is the root of error?

Comment: Try `new_f_w_t = tf.cast(new_f_w_t, tf.float32)`.

Comment: @giser_yugang thanks for your answer. I cant believe that was the case!!!! then why it raises error in the new_f_w_t line?? I mean the line before return while doing histogram!!!

Comment: `K.in_train_phase` requires that `self.rev_entropy(x, self.beta,self.batch)` and `x` be of the same type. But `tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins` returns `int32`  when your `x` is `float32`.

Comment: @giser_yugang Thank you so much for clearing this up. Can you add your answer with the explanations so I can select as the accepted answer

Comment: I also tried filling the argument dtype=tf.float32 which is for return types, but it did not help. so I was totally off this could be the reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`K.in_train_phase` requires that `self.rev_entropy(x, self.beta,self.batch)` and `x` must have the same type in this case. But `tf.histogram_fixed_width_bins` returns `int32` when your `x` is `float32`.  So you need to change type.

```py
new_f_w_t = tf.cast(new_f_w_t, tf.float32)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of why setting dtypes=float32 in histogram did not help? in documentation, it says it is for the type of the returned tensor!

Comment: @sariii Me too. It looks like a bug.